# External site masking our site

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost

Another site, domain.com is mirroring our site.  When you go to domain.com is shows up our site, a live copy.  I've added .htaccess entries to force all sites accessing their domain to have `ourcompany.com` in the URL but it's having zero effect on his copy of our site.

We have an error logging system on our site that logs all SQL errors including the current URL.  This is how we found he was masking our site, one of our SQL errors had his domain name in the URL.

I'm not sure the steps to take....

```
His Domain: bendl.org
Our Domain: ikeyless.com
```

**update**

We updated a page on our site to determine if his "forwarding" was live and it did not update his version.  My only thoughts on this were that he must be hosting a version of our site....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ikeyless.com and bendl.org both point to the same IP... Make a virtualhost for bendl.org, and a redirect to ikeyless.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

This possibly a case for a legal solution rather than a technical one. 
You do have the copyright notice on the page and I assume you haven't granted permission for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

As both domains point to the same IP address your server is responding to requests for both domains (if this were not the case, the other site getting anywhere near your database would be a *serious* security issue). Why someone would do this to you intentionally I don't know, as all the content comes from your server is it unlikely that they can redirect people away to a dodgy site when payment details are entered or anything like that...

Are you on a dedicated service ("real" dedicated/colo or a VPS) or shared hosting? If you are on a shared hosting arrangement you'll need to contact them to report a web server configuration issue (if the server should not know the domain it should respond as such, but some servers are accidentally configured so one of the client sites is the default site instead of the "configured domain" site being so. If you run your own server then you need to look into your web server configuration similarly.

*Regarding your update:*

Could you specify the updated page that is not updated on the other site? If they are both being served from the same vhost config on the same server I'd expect both to update in-step. One appearing not to update could just be a caching issue, or if you are on a shared host it could mean that someone is running a scrapped copy of the site on that same host (hence the IP address being the same) - which reopens the "how does his site know how to see your SQL database" question (could you provide the error logs that identify the other site?).

Comment: We added "Test" to our index page and his didn't update.  My mysql.log shows nothing, it's empty.